# Mocking import with proxyquire works but stubbed function shows as not called

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, nodemailer

I have the following test where I use proxyquire to mock the nodemailer and have it's createTransport return an object with a sendMail function that is a sinon stub.

```
   beforeEach(() => {
        sinonSandbox = createSandbox();
        sendMailMock = sinonSandbox.stub();
        mailService = proxyquire('../src/mailService',
            {
                'node-vault': () => { return { read: () => mockVaultData } },
                'nodemailer': {
                    createTransport: () => {
                        return {
                            sendMail: () => sendMailMock()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )
       
        sinonSandbox.stub(vaultAuthAws.prototype, 'authenticate').returns(Promise.resolve(mockVaultToken));

    });

 afterEach(() => {
        sinonSandbox.restore();
    });


    it('Should call success mail once ', async () => {
        mailService.sendSuccessEmail(userEmail, fileModifiedDate);
        chaiAssert.equal(sendMailMock.called, true);
    });
```

The code under test:

```
const getMailerClient = async () => {
    const smtpCreds = await getCredentialsFromVault();
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
        {
            host: "...",
            port: 2525,
            ssl: true,
            auth: {
                user: smtpCreds.user,
                pass: smtpCreds.password
            },
            tls: {
                minVersion: 'TLSv1.2'
            }
        }
    );
    console.log('TRANSPORTER HERE', JSON.stringify(transporter));
// this prints TRANSPORTER HERE  { sendMail: [Function: sendMail] }

    return transporter
}

 
const sendSuccessEmail = async (userEmail, fileModifiedDate) => {
    const transporter = await getMailerClient();
    console.log("HERE IN SUCCESS", JSON.stringify(transporter));
    // this prints HERE IN SUCCCESS { sendMail: [Function: sendMail] }
    await transporter.sendMail(successMailOptions(userEmail, fileModifiedDate));
}
```

I'm pretty sure the mock is being called otherwise I would get an error but when I run the test this is what I get:

```
Should call success mail once :
      AssertionError: expected true to equal false
      + expected - actual

      -true
      +false

      at _callee$ (tests\/mailService.test.js:62:20)
      at tryCatch (node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:22)
      at Generator.next (node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:118:21)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
      at C:\Users\ekinw\Projects\manage-gp-output-lambda\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:32:7
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Context.<anonymous> (node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:21:12)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need proxyquire to do that, sinon is enough.

Here is the example on how you stub nodemailer createTransport to create fake sendMail function.

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const mailService = require('./code.js');

describe('TEST', function () {
  const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  // Create fake sendMail variable to evaluate later.
  const fakeSendMail = sandbox.fake();
  // Create stub nodemailer createTransport which return object with fake sendMail.
  const stubCreateTransport = sandbox.stub(nodemailer, 'createTransport').returns({
    sendMail: fakeSendMail,
  });

  it('Should call success mail once ', async function() {
    await mailService.sendSuccessEmail('?', '?');
    expect(stubCreateTransport.called).to.equal(true);
    expect(fakeSendMail.called).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

If I run the test code above using your code, it output like this.

```
$ npx mocha code.spec.js 


  TEST
TRANSPORTER HERE {
  sendMail: [Function: fakeInstance] { displayName: 'fake', id: 'fake#0' }
}
HERE IN SUCCESS {
  sendMail: [Function: fakeInstance] { displayName: 'fake', id: 'fake#0' }
}
    ✓ Should call success mail once 


  1 passing (5ms)
```

**Note:**

I change `console.log('TRANSPORTER HERE', JSON.stringify(transporter));` to `console.log('TRANSPORTER HERE', transporter);` for check.